# netbeans - how to run a main class inside a maven war nature project?

Tags: netbeans, spring-boot

Project properties / Run offers only server selection, and run as java application is not offer on the main class..

( springboot project )

Comment: You dont' really run Main class from a war, do you? You just invoke the view (e.g. index.html) from the browser like http://localhost:8080/index.html

Comment: Thank you Ganesh. Sorry it's all about springboot app standalone / tomcat, some springboot app are war and not jar and need to be run through the springboot annotated main class. While using STS it's easy, under netbeans it's not natural.

Answer (score 0):

I finally customized Project properties / Action / run with goal from spring-boot maven plugin

spring-boot:run

And if needed, add properties such as env, profiles and for debug jpda.listen :) all works pretty well now

Env.KEY=value
spring.profiles.active=local

jpda.listen=true